# Manage Large Document libraries and threshhold values

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server

We are using  sharepoint 2010 farm for Document archiving.
In  web application

- content organizer feature is enabled
- documents uploaded to Drop Off Library and content organizer job runs and route documents to Document library
- In document library it has 1300 folders and each folder has 2500 documents

Library settings:

List view threshold :
6902918 items (list view threshold is 12000).
The number of items in this list exceeds the list view threshold, which is 12000 items. Tasks that cause excessive server load (such as those involving all list items) are currently prohibited.
here the no of documents in future will grow

here no of documents increase

1. can I increase list view threshold? or
2. can I route documents to another document library ?
3. can I keep this settings what problems I will face?

Comment: It depends on your actual requirement, for instance, if you have some **XYZ** functionality which needs all documents to reside in same library, then it doesn't make sense to moving the document to another library. Finalize what is actually required, and which will not break your functionalities.

Comment: Technically you are never breaking the threshold because all your items are in folders and you are only seeing 2500 at a time. Do you have a specific problem? Also if your library is exactly as you have outlined you should keep the threshold at 5k.

Comment: there is enterprise search  service configured, until i did not faced problem in view documents and upload documents through custom scan solution, and daily more than 300 users upload documents to this web application and here i am worring in future may be i will face issues like view documents if number of documents increase in this doc library,